# JSBundle with release build

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

I am struggling with connecting "existing" `main.jsbundle` file from another project to my project. It seems like that my `Build Phases` overrides my exported `main.jsbundle` file with `index.js`.

I build my Xcode project as a `Release` so I don't want to use `index.js` file but only `main.jsbundle`. I think that problem is that my `Build Phases` generates `main.jsbundle` from `index.js` and put it there instead of my `main.jsbundle` from the different project.

This is my Build phases script

```
# Type a script or drag a script file faif [[ -f "$PODS_ROOT/../.xcode.env" ]]; then
if [[ -f "$PODS_ROOT/../.xcode.env" ]]; then
  source "$PODS_ROOT/../.xcode.env"
fi
if [[ -f "$PODS_ROOT/../.xcode.env.local" ]]; then
  source "$PODS_ROOT/../.xcode.env.local"
fi

# The project root by default is one level up from the ios directory
export PROJECT_ROOT="$PROJECT_DIR"/..

if [[ "$CONFIGURATION" = *Debug* ]]; then
  export SKIP_BUNDLING=1
fi

if [[ -z "$ENTRY_FILE" ]]; then
  # Set the entry JS file using the bundler's entry resolution.
  export ENTRY_FILE="$("$NODE_BINARY" -e "require('expo/scripts/resolveAppEntry')" $PROJECT_ROOT ios relative | tail -n 1)"
fi

`"$NODE_BINARY" --print "require('path').dirname(require.resolve('react-native/package.json')) + '/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh'"`
```